# Posting XML string in Jersey

Tags: java, junit, jaxb, jersey

I want to send a POST request but i want to add XML as string in the post rather adding JAXBObject. The reason is that i am writing some unit test. With JAXBObject, I am limited to provide only **valid** value in my jaxb generated object via XSD (i.e. valid ENUM Type).

Now i want to test my WS by inputting some random value for that input type so that i can test it.

If i do

```
ClientResponse clientResponse = service.post(ClientResponse.class, jaxbElement);
```

It works fine as expected. However I don't want to send the jaxbElement .. I wana send a custom XML say

Comment: Are you looking to test something that cannot happen with the present code?

Comment: It can happen. The XSD has provided "set" of input status. OrderStatus can only be SHIP/CANCEL ... but this is an xml which will be sent to the client by a user, so he can do some mis-spellings or add some random OrderStatus say "SHIPPED" or "PENDING" etc ...

Comment: But shouldn't then JAXB be throwing the exception and you'd be effectively rewriting tests that already presumable exist within the JAXB code.

Comment: Let assume if XML is permitting only 2 values in "OrderStatus" .. i.e. "Shipped"/"Pending". And assume a client sends an xml with OrderStatus as "Confirm" .. in this case, JAXB would have null in that specific variable and my application would behave accordingly. That what JAXB would do, it wouldn't through the exception. 

For my TestCases, I want to send raw xml, no a JAXB object so that i can tet this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

When you call the following from a test case

```
ClientResponse response = builder.
    accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
    type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
    entity(entityObj).
    post(ClientResponse.class);
```

you can send anything in `entity(entityObj)`

You can also try [SoapUI for REST Tesing](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html)

Comment: I am talking about "RAW XML" now the entityObj or any OBJ class. Please see my comments above

Comment: You can have the `entityObj` as a `String` which contains your raw xml.  So effectively `entity("<XML>.....</XML>")`. If you want more cotrol on your request use `SOAP UI`, it has REST Support also.